# Async thread starts with same objects from parent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

My questions:

1. Is Async thread a child thread?
2. MyObject obj is a local variable in main thread. How can async thread get the same object(reference)? Where does async to get it from?

My below code will end up with obj Name is "Async_Thread"

```
            MyObject obj;
            obj.setName("main_Thread");

            Executor executor = asyncExecutorConfig.getAsyncExecutor();
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                try {

                    obj.setName("Async_Thread");//Async can access obj??

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }, executor);

            Thread.sleep(20000); //to let Async thread run
            obj.getName is "Async_Thread"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `runAsync`, it schedules the `Runnable` passed on the `Executor` passed. This does not necessarily create a new thread, although it might. Typically, it will be run by a thread that has already been created by the `Executor`. Some `Executor` implementations will create new threads when they schedule a task if there are no existing idle threads in their pool, but in general you cannot rely on these threads being a child of the thread scheduling the task for the purposes of inheriting a context class loader, `InheritableThreadLocal` values, etc.

However, objects in general do not "belong" to a thread. Any thread that has access to a reference to an object can use that object.

The specific way that this task has a reference to `obj` is through [local variable capture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#accessing-local-variables). This is a feature of Java that allows lambda expressions to access local variables from the scope where the lambda is defined.

The lambda expression above is equivalent to this code using an anonymous inner class:

```
 CompletableFuture.runAsync(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         try {
             obj.setName("Async_Thread");
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
 }, executor);
```

or this code using a named class with a constructor that takes an instance of `MyObject`:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final MyObject obj;

    MyRunnable(MyObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            obj.setName("Async_Thread");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// ...

CompletableFuture.runAsync(new MyRunnable(obj), executor);
```